# OpenJPA How to use WHERE condition on collection with join fetch?

Tags: join, jpql, openjpa

I use OpenJPA 2.1 on WebSphere Application Server 8.
I have a bidirectional oneToMay relation like this:

```
@Entity(name = "table1")
public class Table1  {
    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private Date date;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "date", targetEntity = Table2.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Table2> table2List;
}

@Entity(name = "table2")
public class Tabl2{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_date", nullable = false)
    private Table1 table1;

    @Column(name = "value", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "INT")
    private int value;

}
```

Now I want to select the whole table1 entity with a condition on table2 like this:

```
TypedQuery<WeekBean> q = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT t1 from table1 t1 JOIN FETCH t1.table2List t2 WHERE t2.value = :value",
    t1.class);
```

But this does not work, beacause I get an ArgumentException:

```
Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1141200 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: " Encountered "f" at character 50, but expected [",", ".", "GROUP", "HAVING", "INNER", "JOIN", "LEFT", "ORDER", "WHERE", <EOF>]." 
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLParser.parse(JPQLParser.java:51)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ExpressionStoreQuery.newCompilation(ExpressionStoreQuery.java:154)
    at org.apache.openjpa.datacache.QueryCacheStoreQuery.newCompilation(QueryCacheStoreQuery.java:262)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.newCompilation(QueryImpl.java:672)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compilationFromCache(QueryImpl.java:654)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForCompilation(QueryImpl.java:620)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForExecutor(QueryImpl.java:682)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compile(QueryImpl.java:589)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:996)
    at com.ibm.ws.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:107)
    at com.ibm.ws.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:34)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:974)
```

How can I use a JOIN FETCH with a condition on the collection?

Best Regards Veote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According JPA 2.0 specification such a construct is not supported, and looks like OpenJPA also does not provide functionality as vendor extension:

> The association referenced by the right side of the FETCH JOIN clause
>   must be an association that belongs to an entity that is returned as a
>   result of the query. It is not permitted to specify an identification
>   variable for the entities referenced by the right side of the FETCH
>   JOIN clause, and hence references to the implicitly fetched entities
>   cannot appear elsewhere in the query.

In your case this means that you cannot define `t2` and as a consequence you cannot use it in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Sorry I only forgot to edit my query. I declared t1 but I get the same Exception

Comment: I modified answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok thats bad :/ Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Not any what I am aware of. Assuming that query is executed in transaction - touching Tabl2 instances by iterating over table2List immediately after query is typical workaround to guarantee that they are fetched.